# How to get filesystem information of a logical volume which is not mounted

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm

In linux, I want to get file system type of an ummounted logical volume. Is there any way to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use blkid command to do that

```
blkid volume-path
```